# Django Create a copy of a Model upon trigger

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering if the following is possible in Django.

As I start my the project, I will create a Model with 'x' fields called BASEMODEL.

I will then create another Model called PROJECT with just 1 CharField.

I will be creating both these in the usual way models.py, makemigrations, migrate etc.

Then as the admin when I add a record to PROJECT with a value 'PROJECT1', is it possible for Django to create a copy of the BASEMODEL called BASEMODEL_PROJECT1 ?

I'm not looking for the exact code, just looking for any ideas or links as to how I could possibly do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sortly answer is no, Django does not able to do that.

But if your question is for managing a multi tenant application, you can check different resources:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/contrib/sites/
- https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants

Hope this can be help you